# Multi Role per User - Acting on Behalf and Acting As in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I gave myself a task to create kind of multi role authentication. To make it short depending on user "act on behalf" value user has different role or privileges.

To illustrate it, say :

1. we have users, companies and projects models
2. user logs in only with one set of credentials user may create and own company, it may also invite other users to that company.
3. by doing so it will gain owner
   permissions and invited users will get subset of those like admin,
   manager or employee
4. user who is an owner or was invited to company has access to data of that company projects depending on privileges granted.

Sound familiar? Teamwork package for laravel or spark teams? Yes but couple of points I need to add and struggle with approach how and where to start.

1. user may be able to browse projects which he is not company owner or invitee of, but only under condition if he was added on distribution list of the project by said company "trustee"
2. when accessing "/projects", "/docs" etc routes, different data is to be served - when user acts on behalf of the company or as regular user.
   The availability to switch the user behaviour to act as is to be available say from drop down menu.

In other words something familiar with Facebook switch to act as page or as individual, when we post as business or as individual.

My first thought was when switching to detach / attach permissions but I think if I have many companies with multiple projects it will make little sense.

Any guidance or criticism is constructive for me. If you know package which already does that let me know please.

Comment: Have you watched the following Laracasts?  It has lots of great advice in it.  https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/16

Comment: Yep I did, this is not the issue here, i want to change role dynamically when logged as regular user to being logged as admin. In other words something similar to mentioned Facebook scenario. So as a regular user I can browse say projects and comment on them but as a company admin or manager I can add bits and pieces to the projects I own etc. So this are different roles depending on use case scenario. When logged as regular user I have no permissions but when switched to act as company manager/owner I have manager permissions for the company and different projects are listed on my projects.

Comment: This may be related to roles as well as so called teams (in my case companies), so to clarify I am looking for solution to switch between teams but also to (no team) stand alone user, as not of all my users have teams. So when I switch to team my user shall have different roles assigned than when it is switched to standalone user. being logged in with the same credentials as mentioned before.